# Is one-instance-per-unique-immutable design pattern considered evil?

Tags: java, .net, design-patterns, memory, language-agnostic

I was reading a chapter on effective Java that talks about the advantages of keeping only one instance of an immutable object, such that we can do object identity comparison `x == y` instead of comparing the values for identity.

Also, POJOs like [`java.awt.RenderingHints.Key`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.Key.html) often use the one-instance-per-unique-immutable design pattern:

> > Instances of this class are immutable and unique which means that tests for matches can be made using the == operator instead of the more expensive equals() method.

I can understand the speed boost with this approach,

But wouldn't this design pattern eventually cause a memory leak ?

Comment: theoretically the jvm is allowed to unload the class itself if it deems it not reachable, and in this way you would free these static referenced objects. I wouldn't worry about objects you yourself don't allocate.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy how could a class be deemed "unreachable" ? Btw I was wondering what's the best solution to implement a cache that uses it's reference value to do equality comparisons?

Comment: @Pacerier: e.g. in a modular application (OSGi, NetBeans Platform), where each module has its own classloader. If you unload the module and with it its classloader all classes of this module loaded by this classloader can become unreachable (if there is no reference from another module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it may cause memory growth (it's not a leak if it's an intentional behavior).  Whether it will or won't depends on just how the uniqueness contract is specified.  For example, if you serialize one of these objects to disk, exit the scope in which it exists, and then deserialize it back from disk, one of two things happens: either you get the same object, or you get a different one.  If you get the same object, then every object every used in the life of the JVM needs to be kept, and you'll have memory growth.  If you get a different object, then the objects only need to exist while there is a reference to them, and you won't have memory growth.

Answer (score 1):

That is sometimes called the Flyweight pattern, especially if the space of possible objects is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding implementing the cache you can choose http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html or you can have bounded LRU cache implemented.

Comment: I mean we could do that for a cache of objects that does not do equality comparisons using their reference value. But we couldn't use that solution for a cache of objects that does quality comparisons using their reference value because otherwise, when it's "recycled", the reference would be different. (and comparisons `x` == `y`) will fail.